# Best Practice For Storing/Reusing Ajax Responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, jsp

I'm developing a spring boot application where on certain pages I have onclick triggers which use AJAX to make requests to obtain data from my database. For example, when a user clicks on a group in the main menu, AJAX will make a request to pull this group and dynamically display it on the JSP page as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".group", function () {
        var groupName = $(this).text();
        $(".groups").hide();
        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            type: "GET",
            url: "/viewGroup",
            data: {"groupName": groupName},
            success: function(result){
                var members = result["groupMembers"];
                $(".focusContainer").append('<div class="groupView">' +
                    '<p>'+result["groupName"]+'</p>' +
                    '</div>');
                $.each(members, function(index, value){
                    $(".groupView").append('<p>Group Members</p>'+
                        '<p>'+members[index]["username"]+'</p>');
                });
                $(".groupView").append('<button class="button addButton" id="addFocus" type="button" onclick="addFocus()">Add A Focus</button>'+
                    '<div class="break"></div>'+
                    '<button class="button cancelGroup" id="deleteGroup" type="button" onclick="cancelGroup()">Delete Group</button>');
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Additional buttons are generated (addFocus) which can for example add members or target goals to said group, however these must be retrieved from the database as only members or goals related to these groups should be able to be added to them.

What is the best practice for retrieving this data after the group is initially selected (After the first AJAX request retrieving the Group data)? Should the members/goals of the group be appended into some hidden div and shown when the relevant buttons are clicked? Should I make another AJAX request when the add focus/member button is clicked? Or should the response of the initial request be stored in a global variable and used by the other .onclick triggers? I'm unsure of what issues could be encountered if storing the response globally in my .js file.

Currently I'm doing a new request for each click but I imagine in production this would become very taxing on the server and cause slow speeds. I've also seen a lot of mention about making asynch:false however there appears to be a lot of debate about whether this is a good design choice or not. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes that depends on your application if you need to allow user to choose only one group then global variable option is good but onces you refresh page it will no longer hold values . Maybe you can try to use localStorage .

Comment: The user will only choose one group at a time, i.e. they will select one which will allow them to delete/modify it and then return them back to the page of groups after they have done so